# Почему создается только первая линия доски?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var Doshka = document.createElement('DIV');
            Doshka.className = "Doshka";
            document.body.appendChild(Doshka);
            var n = 9;
            var m = 9;
            var DoshkaSel = document.querySelector('.Doshka');
                for(var i = 1;i < n;i++){
                    var klitynka = document.createElement('DIV')
                    for(var q = 1;q < m;q++ ){
                        if(i%2){
                                if(q%2){
                                klitynka.className = "Klit";
                                }else {
                                klitynka.className = "KlitN";
                                }
                                DoshkaSel.appendChild(klitynka);            
                        }else{
                                if(q%2){
                                klitynka.className = "KlitN";
                                }else {
                                klitynka.className = "Klit";
                                }
                                DoshkaSel.appendChild(klitynka);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Doshka = document.createElement('DIV');
Doshka.className = "Doshka";
document.body.appendChild(Doshka);
var n = 9;
var m = 9;
var DoshkaSel = document.querySelector('.Doshka');
for(var i = 1; i < n; i++){
    // Создаем столбец
    var row = document.createElement('DIV');
    row.className = 'row';

    for(var q = 1; q < m; q++){
      var klitynka = document.createElement('DIV');
      // Я немного сократил ваши условия
      klitynka.className = (i%2 && !(q%2) || !(i%2) && q%2) ? "Klit" : "KlitN";
      // Клетки складываем в текущий столбец
      row.appendChild(klitynka);
    }
    // Столбец заполнен, кладём его в поле
    DoshkaSel.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.KlitN{
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.Klit{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row{
  float: left;
}
.Doshka{
  width: 180px;
}
```